# 2-dimensional gradient using PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'd like to draw a square with the fill color darkening as one goes up or as one goes to the right.  So, the square should be darkest in the upper-right corner and lightest in the lower-left corner.  Is there a way to do this using PGF commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such shadings are described in section 85.2 of the TikZ manual.  Here's an example of what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{myshadingE}{80bp} 
{color(0bp)=(white); color(80bp)=(black)} 

\begin{pgfpicture} 
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{3cm}{3cm}} 
\pgfshadepath{myshadingE}{-45} 
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: gradient]

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I wanted! I was looking at an old user guide from 2004.

Answer (score 13):

Another possibility is using tikz commands:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\shade[shading=axis,bottom color=black!10,top color=black,shading angle=-45] 
  (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
\end{document}
```

Comment: How could be set rectangle border line  parameters? I tried ... (0,0) rectangle[line ...] (3,3), but error occured.

Comment: @jafan: take a look at `\shadedraw`