# How to iterate foreach with two variables and a list of values

Tags: foreach

Iteration with foreach brings error in the moment I use a list with two variables as you can see in the mwe. Is there a solution possible? As the output PDF shows the error occurs when trying to use a list.
Howto integrate the mwe?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%two variables
\foreach \x   in    {1.00,1.033,...,2.000,2.033,2.083,...,3.000,3.050,3.15,...,4.000}
{
   x \x ;
}

% output 3 series of variables(x and y). 1. between 1 and 2 thirty steps,   2. betw. 2 a. 3 twenty steps, 3. betw. 3 a. 4 ten steps. thats the aim. here  shortened to the end of three(3.000)
\foreach \x / \y in 
   %{1.00/1.033,1.033/1.066}% 0 errors, pdf ok
   {1.00/1.033,1.033/1.066,...,2.000/2.033} % 63 errors, pdf output gen  erated! shows wrong variable contents
   % third version 88 errors, but pdf generated! shows wrong variable values
   %{1.00/1.033,1.033/1.066,...,2.000/2.033,2.033/2.066,2.116/2.166,...,3.000/3.050}
   {
      x1: \x,  y1: \y \\
   }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure, but could you use an alternative notation? As an example: `\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using \x+0.033]  in {1.0,1.033,...,2.0} { x1: \x,  y1: \y \\}`

Comment: @ignasi that gives an emergency stop don't know why. Your syntax is a nice proposal.  But I see no solution for the three series of two variables I need. The addition \x+0.033 must change.

Comment: @gizeh Ignasi's code worked for me. It's very odd that it gave you an emergency stop. Also, how the addition must change? Is the `0.033` addition not a constant?

Comment: My code works for me. You can type this three-part-series with three different `foreach`. Why do you want only one?

Comment: If you want to automatically type complex tables you could also use `pgfplotstable` which is part of `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Alenanno as mwe. the value 0.033 have to become 0.05 in the second part of the list. In the third part 0.10. Have to search for a solution with three different foreach, I think. Can't get rid of the emergency stop.

Comment: @Ignasi I want one, because I can change the width of the step as indicated in the mwe. With the variables I want to draw/fill 30 arcs from 1 to 2, 20 arcs from 2 to 3, 10 arcs from 4 to 5. It's the shading bent tube problem that I want to solve with pgf/tikz. Before I try the "gradient"-solution ([link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172905/how-can-i-draw-a-curved-gradient-fade-in-tikz/173310#173310])with new inst. at worst internet-conn I want to solve that problem with foreach and list. The gradient seems to be the best, but I cannot understand the code yet (biquadratic).

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but if the previous value is always in the next, you can just save it e.g. `\foreach \y [remember=\y as \x (initially 1.00)] in {1.033,1.066,...,2.033} {x1: \x,  y1: \y\par}`.

Comment: You can use a different approach using something like [`multido`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido).

Comment: thanks to all for your answers. Imho this qu. can be closed with one hint for others. Avoid use of list item "..." together with multiple variables, cp. pgf manual 3.0.1.a, p. 902f. `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x / \y in {0/0,10/20,...,90/180,100/200}{
      x1: \x,  y1: \y \\}
\end{document}`  Mwe shows: