# Curve shading rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to reproduce this figure :

[image]

In order to do so, I've only been able yet to do a shaded rectangle with this code :

`\draw [bottom color=gray,top color=gray,middle color= white] (0,0) rectangle  (3,0.3);`

which gives me :

[image]

Is it possible to make a curved rectangle with an adjustable angle and length, 
if I wanted to make the border of a quarter circle with this pattern for example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80171/14500

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations} 
\newcounter{icoord}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    curved pipe/.cd,
    radius/.store in=\CurvedPipeRadius,
    radius=10pt,
    step/.store in=\CurvedPipeStep,
    step=1pt,
    shade/.style={left color=gray,right color=gray,middle color=white}
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{curved pipe}{initial}
{% 
\state{initial}[width=\CurvedPipeStep,next state=cont] {%
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgflinewidth}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}%
    \setcounter{icoord}{0}%
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup-\number\value{icoord}}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}%
    \pgfcoordinate{lastdown-\number\value{icoord}}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{-1*\CurvedPipeRadius}}%
  }
  \state{cont}[width=\CurvedPipeStep]{%
     \stepcounter{icoord}%
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup-\number\value{icoord}}{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}
     \pgfcoordinate{lastdown-\number\value{icoord}}{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep}{-1*\CurvedPipeRadius}}
     \pgfcoordinate{tmpup}{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep+0.3pt}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}
     \pgfcoordinate{tmpdown}{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep+0.3pt}{-1*\CurvedPipeRadius}}
     \pgfmathsetmacro\myshadingangle{0}%
     \path[curved pipe/shade,shading angle=\myshadingangle] 
        (lastup-\the\numexpr\value{icoord}-1) 
     -- (tmpup) to[out=180,in=180] (tmpdown) -- (lastdown-\the\numexpr\value{icoord}-1)
     to[out=180,in=180] cycle;%
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup-\the\numexpr\value{icoord}-1}{center}}%
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup-\number\value{icoord}}{center}}%
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastdown-\the\numexpr\value{icoord}-1}{center}}%
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{lastdown-\number\value{icoord}}{center}}%
  }
  \state{final}[width=\CurvedPipeStep]
  { % perhaps unnecessary but doesn't hurt either
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    \fill (tmpup) to[out=0,in=0] (tmpdown) to[out=-180,in=-180] cycle;
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate,decoration=curved pipe,curved pipe/radius=3mm,looseness=0.7] 
     (0,0) to[bend right] (8,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or without the pipe character, just shaded

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations} 
\newcounter{icoord}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    curved and shaded/.cd,
    radius/.store in=\CurvedPipeRadius,
    radius=10pt,
    step/.store in=\CurvedPipeStep,
    step=1pt,
    shade/.style={left color=gray,right color=gray,middle color=white}
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{curved and shaded}{initial}
{% 
\state{initial}[width=\CurvedPipeStep,next state=cont] {%
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgflinewidth}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}%
    \setcounter{icoord}{0}%
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup-\number\value{icoord}}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}%
    \pgfcoordinate{lastdown-\number\value{icoord}}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{-1*\CurvedPipeRadius}}%
  }
  \state{cont}[width=\CurvedPipeStep]{%
     \stepcounter{icoord}%
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup-\number\value{icoord}}{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}
     \pgfcoordinate{lastdown-\number\value{icoord}}{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep}{-1*\CurvedPipeRadius}}
     \pgfcoordinate{tmpup}{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep+0.3pt}{\CurvedPipeRadius}}
     \pgfcoordinate{tmpdown}{\pgfpoint{\CurvedPipeStep+0.3pt}{-1*\CurvedPipeRadius}}
     \pgfmathsetmacro\myshadingangle{0}%
     \path[curved and shaded/shade,shading angle=\myshadingangle] 
        (lastup-\the\numexpr\value{icoord}-1) 
     -- (tmpup) -- (tmpdown) -- (lastdown-\the\numexpr\value{icoord}-1)
     -- cycle;%
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup-\the\numexpr\value{icoord}-1}{center}}%
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup-\number\value{icoord}}{center}}%
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastdown-\the\numexpr\value{icoord}-1}{center}}%
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{lastdown-\number\value{icoord}}{center}}%
  }
  \state{final}[width=\CurvedPipeStep]
  { % perhaps unnecessary but doesn't hurt either
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[decorate,decoration=curved and shaded,curved and shaded/radius=3mm] 
     (0,0) to[bend right] (8,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is another proposal, full credit goes to Paul Gaborit for [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80207/194703). I changed a few things and stored some parameters in pgf keys: `n` is the number of recursions, `f` is the ratio of the current line width over the previous line width, `color` is, well, the color of the overlays and `opacity` the opacity. Yet conceptually it is really just Paul Gaborit's idea: redo the path in a different color and not with full opacity a couple of times while decreasing the line width.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{% very much based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80207/194703
  pipe beam action/.style={
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pipe/f}*\pgflinewidth,
    draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pipe/color},
  },
  pipe beam recurs/.code={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\level}{#1-1}%
    \ifnum\level=0%
    \tikzset{postaction={pipe beam action}}%
    \else
    \tikzset{postaction={pipe beam action,pipe beam recurs={\level}}}%
    \fi
  },
  pipe beam/.style={pipe/.cd,#1,/tikz/.cd,
  preaction={draw opacity=1,draw/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pipe/color}},
  postaction={draw opacity=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pipe/opacity},
  pipe beam recurs={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pipe/n}}}},
  pipe/.cd,n/.initial=10,color/.initial=white,f/.initial=0.95,
  opacity/.initial=0.1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[draw=black,line width=5pt,pipe beam] 
    (-2,0) to[bend right] (2,2);
 \path[draw=black,line width=5pt,pipe beam={n=25,f=0.96}] 
    (-2,-1) to[bend right] (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice one... :-)

Comment: Great answer, just for fun, for the shaded solution, if I change the line to circle, the output is strange. not sure if we can improve it to fit any shape.

Comment: @lucky1928 Thanks! Yes, this shows how Ti*k*Z decomposes a circle into Bezier curves. I do not know if there is a simple way to improve this.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to `TeX.SE.`

This suggestion only for the shaded rectangle:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[prologue]{xcolor}%
\RequirePackage{pstricks}%
\input pst-grad%

\begin{document}

\psframebox[linewidth=0pt,linecolor=white,fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=black!20,gradend=black!5,gradmidpoint=90]
{\vbox
to 5pc{\vfill\hbox to 12pc{\hfill}\vfill}}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]